# Extracting url from a string with regex and Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm using powershell and regex. I'm scraping a web page result to a variable, but I can't seem to extract a generated url from that variable.

this is the content (the actual url varies):

```
&quot;https://api16-something-c-text.sitename.com/aweme/v2/going/?video_id=v12044gd0666c8ohtdbc77u5ov2cqqd0&amp;
```

`$reg = "([^&]*)&;$"` always returns false.

I've been trying `-match` and `Select-String` with regex but I'm in need of guidance.

Comment: Place `amp` before `;$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what format the content is in.

`(?<=\&quot;)` looks behind "**&quot**" for `(.*?)` which any numbers of non-newline characters and then looks ahead for `(?=\&amp;)` which is "**&amp;**".

Here's a fair start:

```
$pattern = "(?<=\&quot;)(.*?)(?=\&amp;)"
$someText = "&quot;https://api16-something-c-text.sitename.com/aweme/v2/going/?video_id=v12044gd0666c8ohtdbc77u5ov2cqqd0&amp;"
$newText = [regex]::match($someText, $pattern)
$newText.Value
```

Returns:

```
https://api16-something-c-text.sitename.com/aweme/v2/going/?video_id=v12044gd0666c8ohtdbc77u5ov2cqqd0
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operation:

```
$str = '&quot;https://api16-something-c-text.sitename.com/aweme/v2/going/?video_id=v12044gd0666c8ohtdbc77u5ov2cqqd0&amp;' 

$str -replace '^&quot;(.+)&amp;$', '$1'
```